# Online Updating of Regression Model

Tags: regression, online-algorithms

Can Averaging Coefficients and Intercept be used to update an existing Regression Model with new Data Points ?

Comment: Sometimes.  The answer depends on if the data was collected under identical/similar circumstances and your goals.  Can you provide additional details?

Comment: I am dealing with an on-line setting with a continuous stream of input data